# log4j logs to my logfile AND catalina.out

Tags: java, logging, log4j

my logger logs to my logfile and the catalina.out  i don't know how to solve it, I don't want the logger to log to both.

here is my code:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("FA");
```

[...]

```
if(logger.getAppender("walletServicesAppender")==null)
    {
        try
        {

      appenderLayout = new PatternLayout();
      appenderLayout.setConversionPattern("%d %p - %m%n");
      appender = new FileAppender(appenderLayout,"/home/marcel/try/log_file_name.txt");
      appender.setName("walletServicesAppender");
      logger.addAppender(appender);
      logger.setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      logger.error("Cannot access log file: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }    
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      logger.error("Unknown exception: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    }
logger.info("INFO MESSAGE!");
```

[...]

This always makes a double log to log_file_name.txt AND catalina.out

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

```
logger.setAdditivity(false);
```

solved my problem

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which Configurator are you using when you "start" log4j? Basic? Property? Also, any loggers you create inherit from parent loggers (and thus "inherit" their appenders). Did someone configure a ConsoleAppender on a parent logger or even on the RootLogger (which has no appender by default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a `ConsoleAppender` in your log4j configuration, check for a line like

```
log4j.appender.SOME_APPENDER_NAME=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

in your `log4j.properties` file, or something equivalent if your are using XML configuration.

Comment: i have no log4j.properties file yet, because I do all the configuration in code. maybe this is the mistake??

Comment: Maybe you could try explicitly setting "appender additivity" to false in your code. Anyway creating and using a simple log4j configuration file is trivial, I'd go for it.

Comment: thank you so much, this worked for me. I just set logger.setAdditivity(false); then it works THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is another appender attached to your logger, you could try adding this code to find out which appender it is:

```
for (Enumeration e = logger.getAllAppenders(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    System.out.println("A:" + ((Appender) e.nextElement()).getName());
}
```

then look through your source and/or config files to see where it's being set.

Comment: I already thought about that and used logger.removeAllAppenders(); this doesn't help...  i tried your code, this is my log:

[INFO] INFO MESSAGE!
A:walletServicesAppender

just one appander, the one I added before

i think my logger gives it to the rootLogger but I don't know how to forbid this